# How do I call a function through a string matching the name and execute it?

Tags: javascript

I am grabbing the innerHTML off of a clicked list item in an unordered list.  I save this string to a variable and I want to call a function with the same name as this variable.

I've done some research and found some different articles but none of it worked.  eval was referenced as a haphazard way of doing it, but I could not get that to work.  Also another was using Window but the code didn't work for me.

How can I call that variable as a function.  i.e. clickedName()

right now calling clickedName() gives the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: clickedName is not a function
    at HTMLUListElement.<anonymous>
```

Here is the code I am using:

index.html

```
<div id="myDiv">test</div>

    <ul id="parent-list">
        <li>Cats</li>
        <li>Dogs</li>
    </ul>
```

script.js

```
document.getElementById("parent-list").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target && e.target.nodeName == "LI") {
        // console.log(e.target.innerHTML + " was clicked");
        // call function respective to element clicked
        let clickedName = e.target.innerHTML;
        console.log(clickedName);

    }
 });


function cat() {
    const myElem = document.createElement("div");
    let myString = `<div>Meow, Meow, Meow</div>`;

    myElem.innerHTML = myString;

    // put on page
    document.getElementById("myDiv").append(myElem);
} // catClick
```

Answer (score 2):

If the function is declared in the current scope, `this[clickedName]()` should work. This is because the function is a method on the `this` object, and as such should be accessible through it. However, if the function is a part of another object, say `anObject`, you can just do `anObject[clickedName]()`

Comment: Same issue as before--same error.  Tried both ways.

Comment: Can we get some more context on your code? I can't tell you how to call a function if I don't know where or how it's defined.

Comment: I tried doing this[clickedName]() after correct my mistake in the other answer above.  That doesn't work but doing the window object does so you are right too I believe.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

One way that *I would not recommend* is to know that functions declared "normally" (as in, with `function fName() {}` in global scope) are part of the window object, so `doFunction()` is the same as `window.doFunction()`. Thus you can do this:

```
window[clickedName]();
```

But that means users can input the name of ANY function on the global scope to run it, which isn't great. Instead, I'd suggest encapsulating the functions you want to be able to run this way into a specific object holding just those methods; then you can call from that:

```
const allowedFunctions = {
    firstAllowed: function() { /* ... */ },
    someOtherFunction: function() { /* ... */ }
};
// ...then later, to call it...
if (allowedFunctions[clickedName]) { allowedFunctions[clickedName](); }
```

Comment: I tried following this too and it isn't working.  No error is thrown, but nothing happens.  Tried setting a break point in my script.js file in the chrome dev tools, but it doesn't pause on the break point to let me step through and see what is happening when it hits that line.  It just executes anyway.  I also tried the not so good way of doing it with window[clickedName](); and this does not work.  Throws same error as in original post.

Comment: Are you sure that the innerHTML of the clicked target element is the name of one of the functions? What do you see if you console.log out `clickedName`?

Comment: omg, you're right.  I had the function name as cat, yet the li text was 'cats'.  Thank you so much.  Can you explained what is going on there with your code and why it is better to use the second.  I don't understand that fully.  Also, maybe this is a silly way to do this in the first place.  I could have put buttons with click events as the list items and built a menu bar that way to do a one page type app with javascript.  That is what I'm doing.  I wanted to do it without buttons though.  Is this all a silly idea for making everything happen on a single page?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with making it a single page or without buttons. The issue is using an element's innerHTML directly as a function name; if at any point that HTML is not under your control (which it never is), any user can just run arbitrary functions. This is especially problematic if the HTML is ever editable from user-generated content, because then it will run on other users' computers. At least by encapsulating them, you're limiting which functions can run this way. But please remember that click events don't have to be on buttons, they can be on anything :)